# Can a div with content its own specific variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

So I use jquery often but dont actually know much about JS if we are being honest. I am going through W3schools and was working with this specific "try me" snippet

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_datatypes_array

So I thought - maybe I can play with it to make it more complicated and use it in a way that I would when personally coding a layout or UI.

So I created this [JS fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vmf3e3mf/) Trying to put a specific `<div>` as each variable. *I was unsuccessful*. What would be the proper way of achieving this?

Here is my **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vmf3e3mf/)**

**Here's the required code snippet of my Horrible js:**

```
var boxes = [

"<div class='box' id='1'> hello1 </div>"

,"<div class='box' id='2'> hello2 </div>"

,"<div class='box' id='3'> hello3 </div>"

];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = boxes[0]
```

Comment: If you are asking why your CSS isn't applying to your numbered id elements, it is because CSS selector [identifiers must not start with a number](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did in your example is to replace the innerHTML of your demo element with the first element of your array. If you want to render all the divs to your demo element, can use one of the following solutions:

For **modern browsers**, you can use

```
var boxes = [
    "<div class='box' id='1'> hello1 </div>"
   ,"<div class='box' id='2'> hello2 </div>"
   ,"<div class='box' id='3'> hello3 </div>"
];

boxes.forEach(function(element) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += element;
});
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmf3e3mf/1/).

If you need to **support older browsers** (IE8), use

```
var boxes = [
    "<div class='box' id='1'> hello1 </div>"
   ,"<div class='box' id='2'> hello2 </div>"
   ,"<div class='box' id='3'> hello3 </div>"
];

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += boxes[i];
}
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmf3e3mf/2/)

If you care about **performance**, you should go the easy way

```
var boxes = [
    "<div class='box' id='1'> hello1 </div>"
   ,"<div class='box' id='2'> hello2 </div>"
   ,"<div class='box' id='3'> hello3 </div>"
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = boxes.join();
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmf3e3mf/3/).

Comment: Nothing mentioned by OP.

Comment: Why is it hiding the individual Id's css?

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `+=` with `innerHTML`, it will cause the elements inside to be recreated and re-rendered each time

Comment: as mentioned above i am in the process of w3schools tutorial and going in order. I was simply trying to take it a lil farther.

Comment: @PatrickEvans He wanted to use arrays and play with it. If we talk about performance we'd of course join the array and render one string to the innerHTML.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I added a version the joins and puts it into the DOM. Ok for you?

Comment: It isn't just for performance, among other things, users have used `innerHTML+=` and tried to add event listeners inbetween calls and then wondered why their listeners didn't work, which is why I mentioned it

Comment: @MohammadMc `forEach` is not ES2015. It is ES5. It is available in every browser you might want to support.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yea, I trust your experience here. Any actions to take for me to prevent users falling into that trap?

Comment: @MohammadMc IE starting with 9. I update the description.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is that was unsuccessful.
The only problem that I see is that you do not get color from the CSS.
That is due to id being only a digit. If you update your id to b1,b2,b3 (in JS and CSS) you get color.

But it is a bit unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you give me an example of it working with an id?